# Join to nth highest value in another table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I know how to join with the MAX or MIN value of a column from another table, for example:

```
SELECT id, user_id, date_created, invite_date FROM user
INNER JOIN (
SELECT user_referral.user_id, MIN(user_referral.date_created) as invite_date
FROM user_referral
GROUP BY user_referral.user_id) AS invtable
ON user.id = invtable.user_id
```

But how do I do this for the **nth** highest or lower value of `user_referral.date_created` instead of just **MAX** or **MIN**?

Comment: Thats a slow solution but use GROUP_CONCAT and SUBSTRING_INDEX to clip the nth value

Comment: @Mihai Can you provide an example? I don't have experience using those operators unfortunately. Thanks

Comment: Here is an example selecting the second largest value from each group http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb704/6

Answer (score 3):

Just use `limit/offset`:

```
SELECT u.id, u.user_id, u.date_created, u.invite_date
FROM user u INNER JOIN
     (SELECT ref.*
      FROM user_referral ref
      GROUP BY ref.user_id
      ORDER BY ref.date_created
      LIMIT 1 OFFSET 8
     ) invtable
     ON u.id = invtable.user_id;
```

Just as a note, this returns the ninth row, because offset counting starts at `0` and not `1`.

EDIT:

Now I see.  You can do it this way:

```
SELECT u.id, u.user_id, u.date_created, u.invite_date
FROM user u INNER JOIN
     (SELECT ref.*,
             (@rn := if(@uid = ref.user_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@uid := ref.user_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      FROM user_referral ref cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @uid := -1) vars
      ORDER BY ref.user_id, ref.date_created
     ) invtable
     ON u.id = invtable.user_id
WHERE rn = 8;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work as the LIMIT statement means the query only returns one row? I need a complete joined table with all rows. Thanks for the effort

Comment: @emkay . . . Your question is:  "But how do I do this for the nth highest or lower value ".  That does not suggest that you want multiple rows.  If you have another question that involves getting multiple rows -- and you cannot figure out a simple modification to this -- then ask another question.

Comment: The original query I posted as an example returns multiple rows. I wanted the same except instead joining to nth value instead of MAX or MIN. This request doesn't need a new question at all... There is nothing about my question that explicitly states that only one row should be returned.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a `LIMIT N` statement and then doing Max or Min like so (I used 8 for this example):

```
SELECT id, user_id, date_created, invite_date FROM user
INNER JOIN (
SELECT user_id, MAX(user_referral.date_created) as invite_date
FROM (SELECT ref.user_id as user_id, MIN(ref.date_created) as invite_date
      FROM user_referral ref
      GROUP BY ref.user_id
      ORDER BY ref.date_created
      LIMIT 8)) AS invtable
ON user.id = invtable.user_id
```

Comment: Top with mysql...Also no ORDER BY

Comment: Keep mixing that one up

Comment: Consider editing your answer to remove that `top n`; it's bit confusing.